# My phone is no longer listed in Exchange 2010 after upgrading from Exchange 2007. Why?

Tags: windows, exchange-2010

I have moved one mailbox from Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010 and after that, when I select the user in Exchange, where the "Manage Mobile Phone" option is available, there are no mobile phones in the list.

How do I get my phone back?